# Convolution neural network for image segmentation with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to make my first neural network using Tensorflow. I have some medical images and my goal is to segment them. I can't find what I am doing wrong. Here is the error :

```
2021-05-08 14:33:15.249134: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tompi/PycharmProjects/ProjetDeepLearning/test.py", line 185, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs,
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    C:\Users\tompi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:204 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Layer ' + layer_name + ' expects ' +

    ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 input(s), but it received 44 input tensors. Inputs received: ...
```

Below my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras
import segmentation_models as sm
import os
import cv2
import Metrics as metrics # a python file
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

width = 672
height = 448
dataframe = []

def normalize(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))
    # newSize = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
    # newSize[:, :, 0] = image[:, :]
    # newSize[:, :, 1] = image[:, :]
    # newSize[:, :, 2] = image[:, :]
    return image

def createDataset():
    for folder in os.listdir(imagesPath):
        for imageName in os.listdir(imagesPath + folder):
            image = normalize(imagesPath + folder + "/" + imageName)
            dataframe.append([folder, imageName, image])

createDataset()
df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns=['Folder', 'Name', 'Image'])

def getImagesFromFolder(folder):
    L = []
    n, p = np.shape(df)
    for i in range(n):
        if df['Folder'][i] == folder:
            L.append(df.iloc[i][2])
    return L

originalImages = getImagesFromFolder('Original')
maskImages = getImagesFromFolder('Mask')

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(originalImages, maskImages, train_size=0.8, random_state=42)

classes = 3
activation = "softmax"
lr = 0.0001
loss = sm.losses.jaccard_loss
metrics = training_metrics = [
    sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5),
    sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5),
    sm.metrics.Precision(),
    sm.metrics.Recall(),
    metrics.dice_coef
]
batch_size = 3
epochs = 50
callbacks = [tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau()]
```

I am using a very simple Unet :

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(height, width, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.summary()

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

The error says that the input receives 44 tensors which is the number of images in X_train and Y_train `(44, 448, 672, 3)` but I don't know what I am doing wrong, I saw several posts having the same shape and it worked. Can anyone help we. It would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: this is obviously an image classifier...

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: you said image segmentation. it is an image classifier model.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the error. The type of my variables `X_train`, `Y_train`, `X_test`, `Y_test` was `list` and not `numpy.ndarray` because of my function `getImagesFromFolder`. I had to return `np.array(L)` to make it run.